# why are my launch daemons not reloading on reboot of macos

Tags: macos

I have a few launch daemons that used to load when my mac was restarted. Currently I am running macos ventura 13.4.1 and find that they do not reload when starting. When I list the files in /Library/LaunchDaemons I get:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel  1468 Jul 19 18:28 org.me.dowork.plist
com.apple.quarantine      30
```

(Not the actual plist name, of course.) I believe that the quarantine is the problem. But how do I get rid of it and have it work again?

Following are the contents of the file org.me.dowork.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.me.dowork</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/me</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/python3.9</string>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/dowork_daemon</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>00</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>14</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>00</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>14</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>4</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>me</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/workdir/dowork.err</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/workdir/dowork.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I executed

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine
```

as superuser and though it did remove the quarantine extended attribute, it did not fix the problem of not reloading the daemon on reboot.

Comment: I tried xattr -d com.apple.quarantine <pathname> and it did remove the extended attribute, but still did not load on reboot.

Comment: Maybe try re-enabling the daemon now that the quarantine attribute is removed.

Comment: Yes, of course I did that. It showed as a valid daemon and it ran at the proper time. Then I restarted the machine and it was not loaded. So the problem continues.